# Page not found (404) Using the URLconf defined in shop.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

Tags: python, django

Error

Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:9000/accounts/profile/
Using the URLconf defined in shop.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
products/
The current path, accounts/profile/, didn’t match any of these.

shop is my project
products is my app...
After Login my page redirect to another location...
i want another page in (products/templates/index.html) to shown after login..
how i do that

products/urls.py

```
 from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views


 path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='login.html'), name='login'),
```

in views.py i have no function called login

login.html

```
<h1>login page</h1>


<form class="login-form" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group position-relative">
    <label>Username <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
    {{form.username}}
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="form-group position-relative">
    <label>Password <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
    {{form.password}}
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12 mb-0">
    <a href="{% url 'index' %}"><button class="btn btn-primary w-100" 
type="submit">Login</button></a>

    </div>
    <div class="col-12 text-center">
    <p class="mb-0 mt-3"><small class="text-dark mr-2">Don't have an account ?</small> <a 
href="{% url 'register' %}" class="text-dark font-weight-bold">Sign Up</a></p>
    </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

views.py

```
def login(request):
    return render (request,'login.html')


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form  = RegisterForm()
        context = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'register.html', context)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form  = RegisterForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        user = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        messages.success(request, 'Account was created for ' + user)
        return redirect('index.html')
    else:
        print('Form is not valid')
        messages.error(request, 'Error Processing Your Request')
        context = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'register.html', context)
    return render(request, 'register.html', {})
```

Answer (score 0):

In `settings.py`, after `LOGIN_URL` if you have one, else after `STATIC_URL`, add this to redirect user to `index page`. You can change `index` to whatever page you want.

`​LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL​ ​=​ ​'/index/'`

Comment: LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL​ ​=​ ​'/index/'
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid non-printable character U+200B        Error message found

Comment: do you have index url? you should have index url+index view

Comment: index url ? where? in login.html file?

Comment: what is the view function and its url to return index or home page ?

Comment: i am adding my views.py with the post